# grails spring security openId plugin : Unable to login using gmail account

Tags: grails, openid, spring-security, google-openid

I just installed springsecurity core and spring security openId plugins. I am able to login in my application using  a yahoo account, but I am unable to login using gmail account. I am getting the following error message :

> **ERROR consumer.ConsumerManager  - Association attempt, but no
>   discovey endpoints provided.**

I am following the instructions in section 3 here : http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-openid/docs/manual/index.html

I am unable to find any place where I could configure the discovery endpoints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK my mistake the username should be https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id rather than xyz@gmail.com. Answer provided by Burt Beckwith on Grails Mailing List.

Comment: You should write the answer out and mark it correct for rep. Make sure to include the config property you have incorrect so others don't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK my mistake the username should be https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id rather than xyz@gmail.com. Answered by Burt Buckwith. This is not any config property just that user enters this url in username field.